# Send mail with image in base64 (image still not showing)

Tags: image, email, base64

I've searched some information about how to send an email with a base64 image. So outlook would show it even if the user haven't internet access.

So after have developped the function, that's what comes out from my server :

```
------=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary="----=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a"


------=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">some text before image</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<img src="cid:29843881" />
</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">some text after image</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
------=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a-- 

------=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a
Content-Type: image/png; name="29843881.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-ID: <29843881>
Content-Description: 29843881.png

-- IMAGE IN BASE64 with many lines..... --

 ------=b417c3e4c5f511fc316f75b6df52181a--
```

The problem is that in outlook, the image show a corrupted picture. I've tried to make a copy/paste of my image in base64 in this website : http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and it shows me correctly the image.

So does somebody know why my mail is sent but outlook (or any web browser) can't show me the image?

Comment: Do you see your original image, corrupted - or an icon indicating a problem with loading the image? If it is the latter, it could be due to security reasons that the mail client chooses not to display attachments. To make things even more complicated, I saw different behavior by different mail clients.